# Not able to dynamically add the event handler to a button element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In this fiddle, i am not able to get the [Dynamic Event Handler](http://jsfiddle.net/saravanan/YNM68/)

onclick event to be triggered for the dynamically generated button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

even if you add the "onclick" to the button, it is not parsed and processed by browser, and the event handler is never created.

Your best option is create an event handler out of the button itself, remove the "onclick" line, and this in the document ready block:

```
$("#d1").on('click', 'input:button', function() { 
    alert( $("#dataSources").val() );
});
```

this will work as the event handler attaches itself to the #d1, and delegates the event itself to the clicked buttons. If you create or destroy buttons, this does not affect the handler.

Comment: How do I acheive this in version 1.3.2 of jQuery. Our development version has only 1.3.2

Comment: by upgrading to jquery 1.7.1 ASAP!!. jquery 1.4.2 introduces $.delegate, which is equivalent to $.on, solves lots of bugs, and is MUCH faster than 1.3.2. jquery 1.6.2 is very stable too, and I use it in prod. (i still have to validate 1.7 for production, and for some reasons, I like the x.x.2 versions... X'D). But, if you really can't upgrade, $.live is decent option, or you can use $.bind, pass "event" to the callback function, and perform your action in a `if (event.target == 'buttonId') {... ` block.

Comment: Thanks.. I am planning to go for a upgrade, and in the mean time I am using live as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the click event inside the `append` method, you could bind the event using the `on` method within `document.ready` assuming you are using jQuery 1.7.1 as provided in the jsFiddle link.

E.g:

```
$("#deleteDataSource").on("click", function(){
    //do your work here
});
```

Note: I think you should post your code with your question as well.

Comment: Since I donot have the deleteDataSource when DOM is ready, i can't use this code.